# What is the proper way to pass data from userspace program to linux kernel

Tags: dictionary, linux-kernel, mmap

I wnat to pass a key value data to linux kernel from userspace,sometimes may be high frequency to pass data to kernel, is there some efficient way to implement this function?

Comment: Add a sysfs file that you write to from user space.

Comment: @stark Thanks for your answer, could sysfs reach the requirement which the data pass to kernel very often?

Comment: There is a dozen of ways how to communicate between kernel and user space. Study and choose what you think is the best for your case.

Comment: Interrupts are usually the ones used for high freq ops